# Modal is not Closing ReactJS Hooks Using Parent and Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am opening Model (child Component) on Button Click from Parent Component, it opens very well but its not closing and it shows some error:

> Uncaught TypeError: setOpen is not a function from Child Component

Here is My Parent Component

```
<TableCell>
<Button
    variant="contained"
    size="small"
    color="primary"
    onClick={() => deleteHandler(index)}
>
    Delete Me
</Button>
</TableCell>
{console.log(open)}

{open && <AddList open={open} setOpen={open} />}
```

My Child Component

```
export default function TransitionsModal(open, setOpen) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // const [openL, setOpenL] = React.useState(null);

  // const handleOpen = () => {
  //   setOpen(true);
  // };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <h2 id="transition-modal-title">Transition modal</h2>
            <p id="transition-modal-description">
              react-transition-group animates me.
            </p>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Here is my sandbox for reference https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-hoover-p9z7m

Comment: Sorry forgot to add edit button function and I am not on the pc to edit and add it. Pls refer my sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is that you are passing a `Boolean` for the `setOpen` prop rather than the `setOpen` function itself, so change it to `setOpen={setOpen}`.

```js
// RenderList.js

const RenderList = props => {
  // ...
  return (
    ...
    {open && <AddList open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />}
  )
}
```

Your second issue is that you're not destructing props properly in the `TransitionsModal` component. Use `{}` to destruct the `props` object and grab what you need.

```js
// AddList.js

export default function TransitionsModal({ open, setOpen }) {
  // ...
}
```

Here's the fixed example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-wilbur-6eu8b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hi  take a look at this

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-bird-5yh5g

in `RenderList.js`  you didn't pass setOpen

`{open && <AddList open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />}`

also  `export default function TransitionsModal({ open, setOpen }) {`